# Database separation - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a main MySQL db set up, and a class to handle the queries to it. It runs real nice. I am building a custom advertising system on my site and I'm wondering if there is any benefit to creating a separate database all together to handle that system?

Is there any pitfalls to doing it either way?

Option #1 - one DB for main website function, one DB for advertising system

Option #2 - one DB for both main website function and advertising system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you need a new connection for every Database you use, also you need a new instance of your DB-Class - both costs some (minimal) memory. I personally see no reason why you would need/want to do this. If you just want to separate the two things, maybe you could use a prefix like "adv_" for the advertisement tables.

Edit: another problem could come up if you ever want to combine (e.g. join) data of the two databases - you will have a much easier time if you do not use multiple databases.

Comment: Good on the edit - the cost for cross-database joins, even two local databases, is not trivial under any substantial load.

Answer (score 3):

Johnnietheblack, there is no easy answer here, and not even one right answer: different tables need different approaches, and sometimes you have to throw away an academic/more "secure" database model to improve performance & scalability.

It's always a matter of trade-offs. Based on my personal experience, I have some thoughts to share with you:

- When you separate tables in different databases, you have more work to do in your data abstraction layers to keep referential integrity (you have to do the DB chores...) and to link information. On the other hand, it's easier to manage the databases (indexes,  data files, query tunings, etc.).
- Tables with high insert rate and low maintenance (update/delete) and where referential integrity is not *that* important - like log tables - are good candidates to be put in a separate database: although the I/O from inserts are heavy, the records don't change over time, they are rarely retrieved, and their indexes tend to be pretty simple (date/time and some other attribute). I have one case where the log file was so big (millions of records) that at a point a single insert was taking almost 1 sec. Since it has 500 thousand new records each day, it was a snowball: we cannot stop the system to tune the damn thing because it takes too long, and the system was shutting down because this log table was used everywhere and was impacting the business (75% of the procedures used this table).
- Databases can eat THOUSANDS of records for breakfast, so for small tables (less than 1000 records) you generally don't need to worry about, just the big ones ( more than 5000). I have a friend DBA that simply does not create indexes for performance in most of the tables: he made some tests and discovered that their SQL Server was changing the query plan to TABLE SCANS for most of the tables. But be careful here: is strong medicine!
- Try to think about SaaS when it comes to define if a new tables set should be put together inside a database: your advertising system needs to be tightly integrated with your website or it can be a separate component, reusable by other components? If it is the later, you should think about using separate databases, to minimize impacts when you update the schema, do maintenance in the new tables, etc.

There are so many other cases, but alas, we have so little time... The important thing here is to keep an open mind and try to forget a little bit about 3rd form academically perfect database models. Hope it helps!